# Hiding a menu if the parent is on mouse out or the menu itself is mouse out

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I created a simple menu in which when the parent element is hovered over, the menu itself will appear. However, what I'm attempting to do is when the user's mouse is hovered out of the parent element or the menu itself, it will disappear.

The HTML structure of the menu

```
   <div class="tab">
        <div id="shop" class="source tabFace">
            Shop
        </div>
        <div class="tabHidden">
            <?php 
                wpsc_start_category_query(array(‘category_group’=> 1, ‘show_thumbnails’=> 1));
            ?>
            <div class="tabRow source">
                <a href="<?php wpsc_print_category_url();?>">
                    <?php
                        wpsc_print_category_name();
                    ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
                wpsc_end_category_query();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my CSS, I have the `.tabHidden` class to `display:hidden;`

In my jQuery, when the user hovers over the `.tabFace` class, it will animate and make the hidden menu visible

```
$(".tab").each(function(e){
    var parent = $(this);

    $(this).children(".tabFace, .tabHidden").on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).parent().children(".tabHidden").css("display","block");
        $(this).parent().children(".tabHidden").stop().animate({
            "opacity":"1",
            "top":"0"
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it fadeout after the user hovers out of the `faceTab` or `tabHidden` classes.

Comment: Just use the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event handler: `$("#selector").hover(function(){}, function(){})`. The first function is for when you `mouseover`, the second for when you `mouseout`.

Comment: I played with your code a bit, but because there's no CSS, didn't get very far. Superb advice by Luxelin. I just might add that if you are not hovering over the parent, the child will disappear, and not allow you to click on anything in the child. You'll have to come up with more code to keep the child visible if you hover over it.

Comment: much simpler if you nest `tabHidden` as child of `tabFace`

Answer (score 0):

How about using jquery mouseout, create an event for the class and fade each element individually by using this inside the event function.

```
$('.tabHidden').mouseout(function(){
  $( this ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Info:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Here's my problem with this solution: the moment the mouse leaves tabHidden, it'll fadeout. I want it to be if the mouse is out on either TabHidden or tabFace, but not individually, it should be collectively, if that made sense.